# How to add a Flutter API/Module in my app?

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to make an anime app using Flutter. For that I needed an REST API but I fortunately found a dart API. The problem is I cannot understand how to incorporate it in my app. This would really help me reduce the work load.

I am attaching the github link.
https://github.com/charafau/jikan-dart

Comment: Please structure your question in a way whereby off-site resources are not required - ideally with a minimal self-contained code example.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about how to include a package in your flutter Application, then you need to do the following:

1. add the package dependencies in the `pubspec.yaml` file
2. Get the package by running `pub get`
3. and then import the packages in your app using `import`

steps by step instructions also available here: https://dart.dev/guides/packages

also if you check the utilization of the API in the example code, you can find this example:

```
import 'package:jikan_dart/jikan_dart.dart';

main() async {
  var jikanApi = JikanApi();
  var top = await jikanApi.getTop(TopType.manga, page: 2);
  print('result $top');
}
```